# How to restructure/redesign an ever growing adapter class?

Tags: oop, design-patterns

I am working on a game/simulation application that uses multiple mathematical solvers. There is an already existing adapter class for each of them. These adapter classes provide all rendering and functional information for the application.

Broadly speaking, we keep an adapter object to represent an instance and call methods to achieve:

- Generate rendering data.
- modify object state. There are just too many function to do it.
- read data model information for various purposes.

Now the problem is that these classes keep growing over a period of time and carry too much information and responsibility.

My question is how can I redesign/restructure these classes to make better sense. Is there any design pattern I should be looking at?

Edit: As requested, here is the broad list of things any adapter class will be doing.

1. Sync with the current data stored in mathematical solver.
2. Sync with the data model of our application. For things like
       undo/redo.
3. Modify object state:   Change in shape. This is most important and have
           various, more than 50, functions to achieve it. All are self
           contained single service call with parameters. I am trying to insert
           interfaces and factory here but function signatures are not
           compatible.
4. Get data model information of mathematical solver. Like getChildern
       etc.
5. Change visibility and other graphic property.

Comment: Can you provide a more specific list of things your class is doing. Such a list a lone often gives good hints of what can get extracted in extra classes.

Answer (score 2):

The principle to use would be *Information Expert* from [GRASP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GRASP_%28object-oriented_design%29):

> […] Using the principle of Information Expert, a general approach to assigning responsibilities is to look at a given responsibility, determine the information needed to fulfill it, and then determine where that information is stored. Information Expert will lead to placing the responsibility on the class with the most information required to fulfill it. […]

Though never explicitly mentioned, applying this principle will likely lead you to using the patterns given by Martin Fowler in the chapter [Moving Features Between Objects](http://sourcemaking.com/refactoring/moving-features-between-objects) in his Refactoring book:

> […] Often classes become bloated with too many responsibilities. In this case I use Extract Class to separate some of these responsibilities. If a class becomes too irresponsible, I use Inline Class to merge it into another class. If another class is being used, it often is helpful to hide this fact with Hide Delegate. Sometimes hiding the delegate class results in constantly changing the owner’s interface, in which case you need to use Remove Middle Man […]

Answer (score 1):

In general, break down your classes so that each only has one reason to change, per the [Single Responsibility Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle).  Leave your "adapters" in place as a [Facade](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facade_pattern) over the classes you'll extract; it will make the refactor smoother.

Since you describe a list of responsibilities that are common to all your adapters, you probably have a lot of code that is almost the same between the adapters.  As you go through this exercise, try extracting the same responsibility from several adapters, and watch for ways to eliminate duplication.

It would be tempting to start with extracting a class for "Modify Object state".  Since you have more than 50 (!) functions fulfilling that responsibility, you should probably break that down into several classes, if you can.  As this is likely the biggest cause of bloat in your adapter class, just doing it may solve the problem, though it will be important to break it down or you'll just move the God class, instead of simplifying it.

However, this will be a lot of work and it will likely be complex enough that you won't easily see opportunities for reuse of the extracted classes between adapters.  On the other hand, extracting small responsbilities won't get you a lot of benefit.  I would pick something in the middle to start.